# Is there a way to explicitly specify a constructor in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636320/what-does-the-constructor-is-ambiguous-means) explains  the cause for the ambiguous constructor problem, but if I actually want to construct a third-party object which contains such constructors, and I want to pass the argument to be `null`, can I construct the object anyways by somehow telling java which constructor I mean?

In particular, in this example:

```
public Example(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Example(SomeOther other) {
    this.other = other;
}
```

Suppose I want to actually construct a `new Example(null)` using the first constructor. 
Is there some syntax that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Typecast `null`. (whooo, beat by mere seconds Oo)

Comment: You *can* but it would point to a *bad design*. The object should have a nullary constructor if that's a valid way to construct it.

Comment: Note, however, the "third-party". Not the OPs fault :)

Comment: @JohannesH. Or, it's going to blow up when the OP does it. :)

Comment: @BrianRoach I tend to think that if the construction parameters are invalid, a half-decent library should throw. Of course, a half-decent library would also have nullary constructors, as you've already said.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis That was my point re: "blow up", please excuse the non-technical term.

Comment: Agree with everyone that it would be bad design, double-checked the API docs and found that there is indeed a no-args-constructor, but I still believe it is a useful trick to know for the future if I am dealing with such a poorly designed API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, by explicitly casting the null argument: i.e., by calling `Example((String)null);` or `Example((SomeOther) null);`

And as mentioned, doing this suggests a bad design, and I agree. You will want to try to write bullet-proof code where this sort of ambiguity isn't possible or doesn't matter.