# Compilation error coming while using multiple constructors in java

Tags: java, constructor

Below code is running fine and printing `'Constructor B.'` as an output.

```
public class Test
{

    public Test(Object obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor A.");
    }

    public Test(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor B.");

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Test(null);
    }
}
```

But the below code is giving me compilation error `'The constructor Test(Integer) is ambiguous'`

```
public class Test
{

    public Test(Integer obj)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor A.");
    }

    public Test(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor B.");

    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Test(null);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain me the reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5636320/2798643
It says: If you call the constructor with a String object, there's one definite constructor. However, if you instantiate new Example(null) then it could apply to either and is therefore ambiguous.

Comment: @GovindaRajbhar Perfect...!!!.