# Blazor Error - Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, blazor

Creating a UI using Blazor Server-side in Visual Studio 2019.

I have a code block which looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

    namespace ClientsUI.Data
    {
        public class ClientsService
        {
            private readonly ClientsDbContext _context;
            public ClientsService(ClientsDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            private readonly IConfiguration _iconfiguration;
            public ClientsService(IConfiguration iconfiguration)
            {
                _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I run a Debug, the app throws an error at the `CreateHostBuilder` method of `Startup` as such:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
>   constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
>   'ServiceType: ClientsUI.Data.ClientsService Lifetime: Scoped
>   ImplementationType: ClientsUI.Data.ClientsService': Unable to activate
>   type 'ClientsUI.Data.ClientsService'. The following constructors are
>   ambiguous: Void .ctor(ClientsUI.Data.ClientsDbContext) Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration))'

I'm sure this is some kind of noob error - when I comment out the `Iconfiguration` block, all runs fine.  So clearly there's an issue with my syntax - how am I able to implement both of these constructors in this class?

The "why" in your answer would be just as appreciated as the "how," as I'm on my continued learning path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "The constructor ... is ambiguous" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636320/what-does-the-constructor-is-ambiguous-mean)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, thanks - this definitely answers the why.  But since it's related to Java and not C#, I still am not sure on the how?  In other words, how would one re-write this to be able to use both...

Comment: Ah, I totally glossed over the tags. But it definitely still applies. I'll add more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a single constructor, like this:

```
public class ClientsService
        {
            private readonly ClientsDbContext _context;
            private readonly IConfiguration _iconfiguration;

            public ClientsService(ClientsDbContext context, IConfiguration 
                                              iconfiguration)
            {
                _context = context;
                _iconfiguration = iconfiguration;
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, your DI container is going to look for the constructor with the most parameters because that overload defines the most number of dependencies required by your class. The reason you can't have two constructors with the same number of parameters is because the container can't reliably determine which overload you want to use. The container doesn't know how the class will be used, only that something in the system requires an instance of that class. If the two overloads both take in `class` types, then either overload could accept `null` as a value. In such cases, which overload should be used?

Many DI frameworks allow you to selectively choose which constructor is invoked. You'd need to consult your framework's documentation to see how that is effected. But in the general case, when you're not doing selective construction, the default behavior is to choose the constructor with the most parameters.

In this case, you may want to go with selective construction, if available. Otherwise, you would most likely have to refactor the code to be one constructor that takes in two parameters. That doesn't mean that your code needs to use both parameters in any given call, but it does mean that the container will try to new up both parameters, and subsequently any dependencies required by either of those parameters...all the way down the dependency tree. If that ends up being too heavy, then you can look into lazy instantiation for your particular framework.

Comment: This is a great explanation.  Thank you.